# AntMatchers are not working in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I've two URLs in my application:

- `/sa/abc` (which should be accessible to role - ABC)
- `/sa/practice` (which should be accessible to role - ADMIN)

For this I've configured:

```java
http
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/sa/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/sa/abc/**").hasAnyAuthority("ABC")
        .antMatchers("/sa/practices/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
```

I was expecting user with role `ABC` will not be able to access `/sa/practices/link1`, but he is able to.

Also I want to know what will happen to the links which are not mentioned in `antMatchers`. My guess is they can be accessed without any issue regardless of the role.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Order matters. The first ant pattern that matches decides the access. So in your case:

```java
http
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/sa/abc/**").hasAnyAuthority("ABC")
        .antMatchers("/sa/practices/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/sa/**").authenticated()
```

Note that the least specific path is last.